# how to drag and drop,replace views with large views like app icons in home screen in android?

Tags: android

Actually I am new android developer. I want to drag and drop,replace views with large views like app icons of home screen in android, but I could not get solution. Please help me to achieve that feature, Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: What's the link between drag-and-drop on the homescreen with android development? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to move icons around by code? Please clarify!

Comment: I want feature like when I drag and drop widget in place of app icon in home screen of android,the widget will be occupied the app icons space. I want exactly the same functionality.Thanks for giving solution in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these libraries

1. https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid
2. https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

these will help you.

Comment: Thanks for giving solution,but there are all same size views there is no problem to drag and drop items in grid,if there are different size items we need to achieve the same functionality like drag and drop large item with small size item. please help to reach that functionality.

Comment: thanks sanjay and koti....am looking for the same but in my case i need to change the gridview's each grid size dynamically.
suppose in android home screen, app icon has one size and app widget has another size...is there any possibility to change like that?

Comment: hi @gvsharma the functionality you are seeking is not implemented by anyone yet, but you can combine code of [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) with drag sort gridview